# Direct and semidirect products in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Can someone please tell me the necessary codes/commands to enter the below group in GAP.

[image: Group]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous - you need to give the action of $\mathbb{Z}_3$. For example, it may act trivially on one of the $\mathbb{Z}_7$-factors, but not the other.

Comment: Also, this question is pretty "low-effort" on your part - why can't you just google it? (In fact, I just googled it and found a worked example in the GAP documentation: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap49_mj.html)

Comment: I tried according to the information in that link, but at the stage I'm trying to enter AutomorphismGroup() command I'm getting an error saying no method found. That's why I asked... Please help now, I have edited the question by including the description of the group.

Comment: I suggest to edit your question to show what exactly you have tried in GAP. We need to see the actual code and the no-method-found message to suggest something. This will also place the question into the reopening queue. Do not post screenshots of GAP, as they are not usable - you need to copy and paste the text from the terminal and indent it by 4 spaces (e.g. like in the answer below).

Comment: If you can describe the action of $Z_3$ through a $2\times 2$ matrix over `GF(7)`, e.g. `m:=DiagonalMat([2,4]*One(GF(7)));`, you could use the matrix version `SemidirectProduct(Group(m),GF(7)^2);`.

Answer (score 2):

For things like this, I like to work with generators and relators, because then it's easy for me to be very clear about what the automorphisms are doing to the normal subgroup:

```
> f := FreeGroup("x", "y", "z");
> AssignGeneratorVariables(f);
> relations := "x^7=y^7=1, [x,y]=1, z^3=1, x^z=foo, y^z=bar";
> r := ParseRelators([x,y,z], relations);
> g := f/r;
```

Here `foo` and `bar` are the expressions in `x` and `y` that determine your action.

Of course, this gets more tedious when your base groups aren't abelian, but for this kind of group, it's not too bad.

Comment: Can you please tell how to write the relations according to the edited group information present in the question. I tried according to my knowledge but it fails. I'm bit new with the semidirect product, but I need to enter this group in GAP for one of my computations. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika: Once you pick $i$, you would write `x^i` instead of `foo`, and `y^(blah)` instead of `bar`.  You need to figure out what $i$ is, and also what $i^t=$blah is.